How to stack 2 textures in one model, with one having a transparent portion, and the other that can be moved by mapping
So, I am wanting to be able to stack 2 textures on top of each other in a single model. In the pic below, I have a set of eyes that have a transparency in them, and I want to be able to see the Iris texture through the transparent part of the eye texture. I have tried everything, and researched, but I can't find anything regarding this question. Any help would be helpful.

I have the file in the link below if you want to help answer
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1Ud2lUkckY3AtYoPR9jNpwMu7hVdQ6n/view?usp=sharing

It's a bit unclear how you want to manipulate your textures, I'm guessing you want to use UVs.
In this case you need to create an additional UV map for the iris, so that moving the outer eye's UV will not affect the iris, and viceversa (you can do it with a vector mapping node, but it becomes more difficult and unpredictable).
Move and scale the new UV map to fit the iris properly.
Use an Input > UV Map node to choose which UV map to assign (if nothing, the default UV map will be used, that with the photocamera icon active in the UV list).
Now the Alpha value can be used as factor of a mix color node, knowing that black means top socket, and white bottom socket.
If you don't use any 3D shading, set Color Management to Standard (Look None) to preserve textures color fidelity.

